# How can I call multiple PHP scripts with AJAX/JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I am new with AJAX and JQuery. I am trying to use it to call two PHP scripts. I found some examples online but just to call functions. I am just trying to call the scripts so it will load everything on my main PHP file that will then be display on the **screen the results withouth refreshing the page.**

Here is the fiddle example, it works if I put all my PHP scripts in one file : http://jsfiddle.net/vw4w3ay5/

thanks in advance, your help is very much appreciated!

**main_php file (where I want to  call my other PHP scripts):**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">

<script type="text/javascript">

    /*I WANT TO CALL THE TWO SCRIPTS BEFORE EXECUTE THE FUNCTION BELOW*/

                $(".desk_box").click( function() {
             $(".station_info").hide();   // to hide all the others.
                 $("#station_info"+ $(this).attr('data') ).show();
                    });


</script>
```

**display_desk.php (Script I want to call):**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';

//query to get X,Y coordinates from DB for the DESKS
$desk_coord_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";
$desk_coord_result = mysqli_query($conn,$desk_coord_sql);

//see if query is good
if($desk_coord_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}

//didsplay Desk stations in the map
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($desk_coord_result)){   
        //naming X,Y values
        $id    = $row['coordinate_id'];
        $x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos = $row['y_coord'];
        //draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
        echo "<div class='desk_box' data='".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>id:".$id."</div>";
                } //end while loop for desk_coord_result

 mysqli_close($conn); // <-- DO I NEED TO INCLUDE IT HERE OR IN MY db_conn.php SINCE IM INCLUDING IT AT THE TOP?
```

?>

**display_stationinfo.php(second script I want to call):**

```
    <?php
include 'db_conn.php';
//query to show workstation/desks information from DB for the DESKS
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_sql);

//see if query is good
if($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}


//Display workstations information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($station_result)){
                        //naming values
                        $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
                        $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
                        $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
                        $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
                        //display DIV with the content inside
                        echo "<div class='station_info' id='station_info".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>Hello the id is:".$id."</br>Section:".$sec_name."</br></div>";
                    }//end while loop for station_result
   mysqli_close($conn); // <-- DO I NEED TO INCLUDE IT HERE OR IN MY db_conn.php SINCE IM INCLUDING IT AT THE TOP?
```

?>

Comment: and what if you do it with nested ajax?

Comment: I tried doing : $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
                post: "GET",
                url: "display_desk.php"
             }).done(function(data){
              alert(data);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
             });  but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

What about? :

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
<?php
echo "<script>";
include "display_desk.php";
include "display_stationinfo.php";
echo "</script>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /*I WANT TO CALL THE TWO SCRIPTS BEFORE EXECUTE THE FUNCTION BELOW*/

                $(".desk_box").click( function() {
             $(".station_info").hide();   // to hide all the others.
                 $("#station_info"+ $(this).attr('data') ).show();
                    });


</script>
```

To be sure add $(document).ready(function(){

});

/*EDIT*/
Hum you want to use Ajax . did you try with :

```
$.post("yourURL.php",function(html){
    /*here what you want to do*/
    /*return of your script in html*/
});
```

Comment: what's the difference from having that in PHP and not just put it where my JQuery function is? my display_stationinfo.php will have data that I will want to display LIVE later on. I don't just want to "include those scripts" in my main php file

Comment: Hum you want to use Ajax . did you try with :

$.post("yourURL.php",function(html){
    /*here what you want to do*/
    /*return of your script in html*/
});

Comment: what do you mean "here what yo want to do" ? I just want to call the scripts, it will do the SQL queries on its own and display it on the main php file.

Comment: i don't understand what do you want to do ... why $.post dosn't work?